# Unable to download the Postman collection and the environment provided in the Smart-car-use-case - mimik

Tags: javascript, microservices, edgeengine, edgesdk

I have been trying to solve one of the use cases provided in the mimik website, the **Smart-car-use-case**. In that under the "**Requirements**" option it was mentioned to '***download Postman collection and the environment provided below in Table 1***'. But I was not able to find any required files and Table 1.[image]

Comment: Where ever you are reading the instructions should also have provided a postman collection with the environment file. The instruction to you is to import it to your postman tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please revisit this page and reload. We have updated said page to include the missing files that are required.

https://developer.mimik.com/smart-car-use-case/